# Timezone configuration for Auth0

Tags: auth0

I am currently testing user last login log data created by Auth0 and noticed that it is not using the time zone I am using but it seemed like it was using their own timezone. My question is, which timezone are they using? And if possible, can I change Auth0 configuration so that it can provide log data based on timezone I am using?